# Create table from another tablo column that have pipeline strings

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table. It contains 2 columns (id,value). Value columns holds date and status.(a:active,s:suspend,d:deactive)

```
id | value
1  | 220325a|220608s
2  | 220325a|220325d|220822a|220822d
3  | 220325a
4  | 220325a|220329d
```

What i want to do is to parse value columns like that

```
My new table :

 id | start_date | end_date
 1  | 25.03.2022 | 08.06.2022
 2  | 25.03.2022 | 25.03.2022
 2  | 22.08.2022 | 22.08.2022 
 3  | 25.03.2022
 4  | 25.03.2022 | 29.03.2022
```

I think I have to use nested loop but how do i find dates one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive query and simple string functions:

```sql
WITH bounds (id, value, spos, mpos, epos) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         1,
         INSTR(value, '|', 1, 1),
         INSTR(value, '|', 1, 2)
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         value,
         epos + 1,
         INSTR(value, '|', epos + 1, 1),
         INSTR(value, '|', epos + 1, 2)
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  epos > 0
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id SET order_id
SELECT id,
       TO_DATE(SUBSTR(value, spos, 6), 'RRMMDD') AS start_date,
       CASE 
       WHEN mpos = 0
       THEN NULL
       ELSE TO_DATE(SUBSTR(value, mpos + 1, 6), 'RRMMDD')
       END AS end_date,
       SUBSTR(value, spos + 6, 1) AS start_status,
       CASE 
       WHEN mpos = 0
       THEN NULL
       ELSE SUBSTR(value, mpos + 7, 1)
       END AS end_status
FROM   bounds;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, value) AS
SELECT 1, '220325a|220608s' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '220325a|220325d|220822a|220822d' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '220325a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '220325a|220329d' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | START_DATE | END_DATE | START_STATUS | END_STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-25 00:00:00 | 2022-06-08 00:00:00 | a | s |
| 2 | 2022-03-25 00:00:00 | 2022-03-25 00:00:00 | a | d |
| 2 | 2022-08-22 00:00:00 | 2022-08-22 00:00:00 | a | d |
| 3 | 2022-03-25 00:00:00 | *null* | a | *null* |
| 4 | 2022-03-25 00:00:00 | 2022-03-29 00:00:00 | a | d |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6sScBFSW)